# Issue with &nbsp; in texbox

Tags: asp.net

I want to avoid, and get rid of, any blank space that is showing up like this in my textbox `"&nbsp;"` How can I not show this blank space when the page loads?  I am using a popup model extender so when it loads I get the blank space which causes an error when I try to save the data.

Here is my textbox:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="BO_Start"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Start" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't get what the problem is, but I would use the self closing tag `<asp:TextBox ID="Start" runat="server"/>` so there can not be content without setting the `value` attribute.

Comment: thnx, when the page loads i may or may not have any data in the textbox however, i get something like this inside the textbox: "&nbsp;" which means it is blank when there is no data that is coming from the backend.  But what i need is not to show this "&nbsp;" if there is no data

Comment: Does the data coming from the server contain `&nbsp;`?

Comment: it shows in the table like this: Null

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set the text of your textbox?

Comment: I have a hunch that you are probably doing: `textBox.Text = " "`, if you just want it to be empty just do `textBox.Text = String.Empty`

Comment: @moe the table may show null, but what is actually coming from the server?  If you find where you're doing `Start.Text = whatever` what is the value that is getting set to the Text property of the textbox?

Comment: sorry for the delay, here it is: Start.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;